# During JIRA build issue with frontend-maven-plugin and Yarn

Tags: maven, npm, jira, yarnpkg

Im trying to build JIRA from source, following steps given in

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/building-jira-from-source/

**OS:** Windows 10

**JIRA version:** 7.6.2

Im getting following error during build process (build.bat)

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (yarn install) on project jira-project: Failed to run task: 'yarn install --production --frozen-lockfile --prefer-offline --mutex network --no-progress' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (yarn install) on project jira-project: Failed to run task
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run task
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:100)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException: 'yarn install --production --frozen-lockfile --prefer-offline --mutex network --no-progress' failed.
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.YarnTaskExecutor.execute(YarnTaskExecutor.java:64)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.YarnMojo.execute(YarnMojo.java:65)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:94)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutionException: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:82)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput(ProcessExecutor.java:64)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.YarnExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput(YarnExecutor.java:28)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.YarnTaskExecutor.execute(YarnTaskExecutor.java:58)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:74)
        ... 26 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@atlassian/jira",
  "//": [
    "We have some first-order deps (and not dev deps) of JIRA.",
    "Everything in dependenceis assists in building the source itself.",
    "Anything in the dependencies group MUST:",
    "- be available in a public NPM repo",
    "- be licensed according to https://extranet.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2030896290",
    "- work in the JIRA source build"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@atlassian/jira-server-gulp-tasks": "file:conf/frontend/gulp",
    "babel": "6.5.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode": "6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.18.0",
    "bluebird": "",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-debug": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-newer": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-help": "1.6.1",
    "maven": "^4.0.3",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.17",
    "yargs": "5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@atlassian/eslint-config-jira-fecq": "^3",
    "@atlassian/fecq-enforcer": ">=5.1.2",
    "@atlassian/stylelint-config-jira-fecq": "^1",
    "amd-conversion-analyser": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "eslint": ">=3.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "0.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^1.0.5",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.33.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
    "glob": "7.1.1",
    "gulp-filter": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-merge": "0.1.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "1.1.0",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.11",
    "stylelint": "^7"
  },
  "//": "These versions are also defined in the root pom.xml and other package.json files. Keep them in sync!",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~8",
    "npm": "~5",
    "yarn": "~1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "amd": "amd . --globals",
    "preinstall": "./conf/frontend/node ./conf/frontend/npm/preinstall.js",
    "postinstall": "./conf/frontend/node ./conf/frontend/npm/postinstall.js",
    "lint": "fecq-enforcer --all --format stylish || true",
    "watch": "gulp watch",
    "process-resources": "gulp process-resources"
  }
}
```

POM.xml:

```
        <!-- node -->
        <nodeVersion>v8.1.4</nodeVersion>
        <npmVersion>5.0.3</npmVersion>
        <yarnVersion>v1.2.1</yarnVersion>
```

Comment: Please show your frontend-maven-plugin configuration in the pom.xml file from the module which is failing.